# How to pass arguments to a fragment using bottom navigation view and Android Navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Is it possible to pass and access arguments in a fragment using a bottom navigation view and the Navigation component?

I'm using a one activity with many fragments approach where my top level fragment requires an argument(Usually done via the newInstance generated method). I've had a look at the Navigation component developer guide and the codelab but it only mentions using safeargs and adding argument tags in the destinations and actions.

Here's my navigation graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
          android:name="uk.co.homeready.homeready.HomeFragment"
          android:label="fragment_home"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
          <!--Do I create an argument block here?-->
    </fragment>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/calculatorFragment"
          android:name="uk.co.homeready.homeready.CalculatorFragment"
          android:label="fragment_calculator"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_calculator"/>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/resourcesFragment"
          android:name="uk.co.homeready.homeready.ResourcesFragment"
          android:label="fragment_resources"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_resources"/>

</navigation>
```

Bottom Navigation View menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_home"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/calculatorFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_attach_money_24px"
        android:title="@string/title_calculator"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/resourcesFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_library_books_24px"
        android:title="@string/title_resources"/>

</menu>
```

MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, 
        R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
        ....
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

HomeFragment

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val argument = //TODO access argument here
    ...
}
```

Comment: So you want your `homeFragment` to be started with some default set of arguments when you tap on it from the bottom nav? Are you reusing the `homeFragment` somewhere else with different arguments then or are they always just fixed values?

Comment: Yes for my usecase I would like to pass some default set arguments when you tap the bottom nav. I would also possibly reuse homeFragment somewhere else too.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to pass arguments to destinations that is tied to menu items. Try to use 'OnDestinationChangedListener' inside your activity onCreate method, something like this:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        when(destination.id) {
            R.id.homeFragment -> {
                val argument = NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(6).build()
                destination.addArgument("Argument", argument)
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

If you want that your start destination will receive default arguments the implementation should be different.
First, remove 'app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"' from your 'NavHostFragment' xml tag.

Then, inside your activity onCreate you need to inflate the graph:

```
 val navInflater = navController.navInflater
 val graph = navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph)
```

Then add your arguments to graph(this arguments will be attached to start destination)

```
val navArgument1=NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue(1).build()           
val navArgument2=NavArgument.Builder().setDefaultValue("Hello").build()
graph.addArgument("Key1",navArgument1)
graph.addArgument("Key2",navArgument2)
```

Then attach the graph to NavController:

```
navController.graph=graph
```

Now your first destination should receive the attached arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex. I'm retrieving the the argument in the HomeFragment via  `val argument = arguments?.getString("Argument")` However on app start up `argument` is null in HomeFragment even though I can see that the listener is being called and the argument is being created in the main activity. I have to tap on another item in the bottom nav and then tap and navigate back to HomeFragment in order for `argument` to return something

Comment: The reason why the `OnDestinationChangedListener` only works the second time is because that is called after the `navigate()` call is done and the arguments are set for the first Fragment. Adding the `<argument>` to the graph is the exact equivalent to manually creating a `NavArgument` at runtime and is the recommended approach.

Comment: I tried first approach, OnDestinationChangedListener is not working on very first time.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'm having the same problem where `OnDestinationChangedListener` doesn't work the first time. I added my argument to the destination through xml aswell, but it still didn't work. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to do this is indeed with an `<argument>` block on your destination.

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
      android:name="uk.co.homeready.homeready.HomeFragment"
      android:label="fragment_home"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
      <argument
          android:name="Argument"
          android:defaultValue="value"
          />
</fragment>
```

This will automatically populate the arguments of the Fragment with the default value without any additional code needed. As of Navigation 1.0.0-alpha09, this is true whether you use the Safe Args Gradle Plugin or not.

Comment: How can i receive these arguments in destination fragment?

Comment: @NaumanAsh - how you receive the arguments, be it via Safe Args or not, is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args)

Comment: @ianhanniballake Can we change the argument value programmatically when an item is tapped from the `bottomNavView`?

Comment: Where are these arguments populated from? The main activity?

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 - the `android:defaultValue` means that this argument is always added, no matter how you `navigate` to that fragment.

Answer (score 3):

Default values was not usable for me, because I have dynamic menu items that could have multiple of the same destination with different arguments. (changed from server)

Implement BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener:

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val fragmentId = item.itemId
    val arguments = argumentsByFragmentId[fragmentId] // custom mutableMapOf<Int, Bundle?>() with arguments
    navController().navigate(fragmentId, arguments)
    return true
}
```

To use that you will takeover the navigation, by replacing the listener. The order of calls here are important:

```
bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

My argument was already defined in the nav graph xml and not sure why but @Alex's answer didn't work for me, instead I did this (from the destinationChangedListener):

```
 arguments?.putParcelable("argname", argvalue)
```

Note I was using this to give a specific response when deep linking to a particular nav bar tab. By default I needed to also do this (to avoid the same bundle getting re-used and deep link handling happening again):

```
arguments?.remove("argname")
```