# When using Navigation Component, how do I set an argument at runtime for a destination accessed via navigation view menu?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation, navigationview, android-navigationview

I have a navigation drawer with a navigation view with menu items and I'm using navigation component. How do I specify an argument for a destination at runtime when a certain menu item in the navigation view is clicked?

I know I can set default arguments in the nav graph but this is not what I want to do because the argument passed needs to be decided at runtime. For toolbar menu items, I have no issue as I'm able to override `onOptionsItemSelected`. My issue is specifically with menu items in the navigation view.

I have tried the approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54086631/10933532 but I am unable to create a `NavArgument` as described. The `NavArgument` class does not give me the public `Builder()` constructor.

I set up my navigation view with the navigation controller in mainactivity onCreate like this:

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navController);
```

I also do this to set up my toolbar with the navigation controller:

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(collapsingToolbarLayout,toolbar,navController,appBarConfiguration);
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom `NavigationItemSelectedListener`.

Pay attention because in this way you are removing the original listener. You have to call **`NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected()`** to trigger the default behavior.

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.xxxxx -> {
                // handle click
                true
            }
         }
         //Call the original listener
         NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(it, navController)
         drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
         true
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this has worked. Is my need to pass a non-default argument to a menu item code smell/bad practice or should I just proceed with your suggested workaround?

Comment: @thebutcher_254 It is difficult to have an opinion without knowing the entire context/project.